# Java - generic class parameter with a generic parameter

Tags: java, templates, generics, inheritance

how do I correctly write following class declaration in Java?

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends BinarySearchNode<E implements Comparable<E>>> implements Iterable<E>
```

Basically, I am trying to create a BinarySearchTree of any class T that inherits BinarySearchNode of a Comparable datatype E (And my BinarySearchTree should also be Iterable).

How can I properly declare that class in Java?
Thanks!

Comment: Why does this thing take the *node type* instead of the *element type* as a type parameter?

Comment: Because I want classes which extend BinarySearchTree to be able to replace the BinarySearchNode with a different class that extends it.
For example - An AVLTree would extend BinarySearchTree and use an AVLNode instead of the BinarySearchNode

Comment: Obviously, I'm not expecting anyone to give me the class implementation,
If you read my question carefully you'd understand I'm only looking for the correct way to write the line I posted above.

Comment: Perhaps my phrasing was not clear, suggestions for a better way to put my question?

Comment: SIde question... Shouldn't your class be `Iterable` on the values i.e. `E` instead of on the node?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner that's a good question! In fact I agree with you, will edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: Another suggestion... I would change `E extends Comparable<E>` for `E extends Comparable<? super E>`. This would allow you to have a tree of i.e. `Dog` with `Dog` being a subclass of `Animal` and `Animal` being `Comparable`. I mean that you could use the `compareTo` method from one ancestor of the element type of your tree, and you shouldn't need to implement `compareTo` in `Dog` (using the one from `Animal` would suffice, if it's good enough).

Comment: All this with that only change from `<E>` to `<? super E>`. If you are interested on this topic, you should read about [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Comment: That's new to me, thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends BinarySearchNode<E>, E extends Comparable<E>> implements Iterable<E>
```

The type parameter E needs to be defined separately from the node type, even if it ends up looking redundant: `BinarySearchTree<BinarySearchNode<String>, String>`. Java won't let you directly access a generic parameter of a generic type.

Also, note that generic parameters always use "extends" even with interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

With Generics in Java, you will only use `extends`.  So, essentially your method decoration would become:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends BinarySearchNode<E extends Comparable<E>>> extends Iterable<T>
```

Even for those classes that implement an interface, generics will use `extends`.  The only other syntax for generics is `super` if you are looking at the inheritance from the opposite direction

Comment: This does not compile. You cannot nest generics' extends in a class definition, i.e. you cannot have `class A<T extends B<E extends C>>`. Besides, `Iterable` is an interface, so you must use the keyword `implements` if the class acutally implements it, it cannot be extended.